# Schluter®-KERDI-DRAIN hair catcher

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain

I just had a [Schluter®-KERDI-DRAIN](https://www.schluter.com/schluter-us/en_US/Shower-System/Drains/Schluter%C2%AE-KERDI-DRAIN/p/KERDI_DRAIN) installed in the shower.

[image]

After a few weeks it's been working fine.

Out of curiosity I unscrewed the grate to see the hair situation and only found a few clumps hanging on the pipe.

Do I need a hair catcher for this drain?

If so, which would you recommend? [Designer Drains sells hair catchers](https://designerdrains.com/product/hair-catcher/), however I haven't been able to find other products or reviews.

That gives me a feeling that this particular drain doesn't need a hair catcher. Although I'd hate to be wrong in a few months or years.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that drain.  Is it merely decorative or does it serve a specific function beyond a basic drain?

Answer (score -2):

Schluter KD-STR fits inside the Kerdi drain and is a purpose built hair strainer.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Schluter-Kerdi-Drain-ABS-Strainer-KD-STR/309686213?irgwc=1&im_rewards=1&cm_mmc=afl-ir-2003851-1420157-EdgeBingFlow&clickid=y%3AUVm22UOxyIWe7TPFXHQXKDUkFSicX5zRnG3w0